# How do I trap exceptions in my Ionic app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to catch exceptions in my Ionic app so I can log them in my log handler, but none of the ways I've tried seem to work.

I'm triggering an exception by referencing an undefined variable. I can see the exception get caught and logged in the JavaScript console, but I can't find any way to get notified about it in my app.

First, I tried window.onerror like this:

```
window.onerror = function(message, url, lineNumber, columnNumber, error) {
    log.error('caught javascript exception: ' + message + ' at ' + url + ' ' + lineNumber + ':' + columnNumber);
    return true;
};
```

That didn't catch it. Then I tried overriding $exceptionHandler, as described here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler. Here's my code for that:

```
angular.module('exceptionOverride', []).factory('$exceptionHandler', function() {
    return function(exception, cause) {
        log.error('angular exception: ' + exception.message + ' (caused by ' + cause + ')');
    };
});
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work either. In both cases, I still see the exception get logged in the JavaScript console, but not by my handler.

For completeness, here's what the exception looks like when it gets logged to my console (running with ionic's live update, `ionic run android -c -l -s`):

```
40    499948   error    ReferenceError: x is not defined
at EquipAdminController.vm.causeException (http://192.168.2.194:8100/js/bundle.js:1336:44)
at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.2.194:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21972:15), <anonymous>:2:265)
at http://192.168.2.194:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:55803:11
at Scope.$eval (http://192.168.2.194:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24673:28)
at Scope.$apply (http://192.168.2.194:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24772:23)
at HTMLButtonElement.listener (http://192.168.2.194:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:55802:15)
at Object.triggerEvent [as trigger] (http://192.168.2.194:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:811:15)
at Object.touchGesture [as handler] (http://192.168.2.194:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2005:14)
at Object.detect (http://192.168.2.194:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:1389:30)
at Object.startDetect (http://192.168.2.194:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:1363:12)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: may be its problem with your handler then.. can you tell more about your handler

Comment: It's not my handler. If I replace my log.error() calls with console.log(), I still don't see the messages.

Comment: i dont see `log` being inject into this exception handler module. angularjs provide `$log` and not `log`

Comment: log is my custom handler that uses console.log. As I said above, if I replace my log.error() calls with console.log(), the problem still exists.

Comment: yes, but where are you injecting log, into the exceptionOverride module?? you have to inject whatever services you have, else how will you have handle to it. unless its window.log

Comment: I don't need to inject $log into the exceptionOverride module because I'm not using it.

Comment: I found a workaround by adding a decorator to angular's $log. This lets me intercept the $log.error calls that are happening for most (all?) exceptions. Not exactly what I was looking for, but it seems to work.

Comment: you can put that as an answer, it will help future readers

Comment: that workaround still misses errors that don't go through $log.error correct? I think I have done the exact same process as you with my own log service and having the same results

Comment: Yes, it does miss things that don't go through $log.error. However, every exception I've seen so far does go through $log.error, so I'm thinking Angular or Ionic has some top-level exception handler that uses $log.error.